# Why networkx list(g.edges) does not return int?

Tags: networkx, edges

`pair = list(g.edges()) print(pair)`

Why is the result of the second node is not an 'int'?
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsxE5.png)

I used `firstnode = pair[a][0]`, `secondnode = int(pair[a][1]` for converting the number of the second node from a float to an int.
But I am still confused why it is float?

Comment: Hi.  In order to help, we need to know more about what you are expecting the output to be.  The short answer is `pair` is a list of edges.  it's not an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I am not entirely sure how your code looks like, but since you have for all of the edges in your graph a float as the second number and you want to type it as an integer, I would suggest you to do this:

**My code example:**

```
import networkx as nx

# Create dummy graph
g = nx.Graph()
g.add_edge(1,2.0)
g.add_edge(5,4.3)
g.add_edge(8,3.9)

# Get list of all edges
pair = list(g.edges())
print(pair)

# Iterate through all edges
for a in range(len(g.edges())):
  # Get first node of edge
  firstnode = pair[a][0]
  # Get second node of edge and type cast it to int
  secondnode = int(pair[a][1])
  # Print nodes / or execute something else here
  print(firstnode,secondnode)
  print()
```

**And this is the output:**

```
[(1, 2.0), (5, 4.3), (8, 3.9)]
1 2

5 4

8 3
```

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question - to descibe my case - if  I print my edges of nodes:

```
for edge in G.edges():
  print(edge)
```

Gives:

```
('1', '11')
('1', '6')
('2', '2')
...etc
```

Meaning the nodes IDs were STRINGS not INT. SO for example, you would need:

```
print("Node {} has degree {}".format(node_id, G.degree[node_id]))
print("Node {} has degree {}".format('1', G.degree['i']))
```